# How to prove that $\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty}f(x)=0$

Tags: calculus

We know $\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty}f'(x)=c$,

how to prove that $\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty}f'(x)=0$

Comment: You cannot!. Unless you can prove that every real number is $0$ -:)

Comment: Did you mean $\lim_{x\to\infty} f(x) = c \,\,\,??$

Comment: Sorry, it is my mistake.

Comment: I have updated the question

Comment: You still have to remove $'$ from the last equation

Answer (score 1):

Let $f(x)=x$. Then $\lim_{x\to\infty}f'(x)=1\ne0$.

Let $f(x)=\log(x)$. Then $\lim_{x\to\infty}f'(x)=0$ but $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)$ does not exist.

Let $f(x)=\dfrac{\sin(x^2)}{x}+c$. Then $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=c$ but $\lim_{x\to\infty}f'(x)$ does not exist.

Seems hard to "fix" the original statement.